# Can this be classified as an ANCOVA?

Tags: model, ancova

```
ModA <- lm(Temperature ~ Section*sin(2*pi*t)+Seccion*cos(2*pi*t),data=MyData)
ModB <- lm(Temperature ~ Section+sin(2*pi*t)+cos(2*pi*t),data=MyData)
```

I have to specify the statistical methods in my paper so, is it correct to say that these are ANCOVA models or they are only linear models with parallel slopes and interactions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ANCOVA is terminology that some fields use to mean "linear regression with continuous and categorical variables". If Section is categorical and t is continuous, then I'd say this fits the ANCOVA bill.